# PowerBI/Powerquery - "Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from transport stream" while 'Applying Changes'

Tags: powerbi, exchange-server, powerquery

I have a powerBI that grabs data from 4 outlook mailboxes from Microsoft Exchange Server. Each mailbox is a separate query and they each have identical columns.

With these separate mailbox queries, I append the data from each mailbox into 1 new query and then expand the `Sender` field into `Sender.Name` and `Sender.Address` and perform a pivot.

I believe the total number of records is under 50,000, but Powerbi takes multiple hours to apply changes only to eventually return an error `Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from transport stream"` . What is happening here?

If I delete all the steps in the Appended query, the changes apply successfully after several minutes, but I do require the additional steps unfortunately.

EDIT: if I just `Append` instead of `Append as New`, it seems to work without errors. I want to end the day on a high note so I dare not try refreshing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending to existing query rather than appending to a new query yielded no error message. Explanation: unknown.